# GCS Python access from colab

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-colaboratory

I am trying to access GCS from Colab using the following lines of code and get the given error. Am I missing something? Or Colab doesn't support this kind of GCS access? Is there any workaround or best practices I can use?

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client()
bucket = client.get_bucket('busnet_videos')
blob = bucket.blob('my-test-file.txt')
blob.upload_from_string('this is test content!')
```

Error :

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-7-0ed440d78c8f> in <module>()
      7 from google.cloud import storage
      8 
----> 9 client = storage.Client()
     10 bucket = client.get_bucket('busnet_videos')
     11 blob = bucket.blob('my-test-file.txt')

2 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/storage/client.py in __init__(self, project, credentials, _http)
     71             project = None
     72         super(Client, self).__init__(
---> 73             project=project, credentials=credentials, _http=_http
     74         )
     75         if no_project:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/client.py in __init__(self, project, credentials, _http)
    221 
    222     def __init__(self, project=None, credentials=None, _http=None):
--> 223         _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project)
    224         Client.__init__(self, credentials=credentials, _http=_http)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/google/cloud/client.py in __init__(self, project)
    176         if project is None:
    177             raise EnvironmentError(
--> 178                 "Project was not passed and could not be "
    179                 "determined from the environment."
    180             )

OSError: Project was not passed and could not be determined from the environment.
```

Comment: Try specifying your project id when you instantiate the client: `client = storage.Client("your-project-id")`. I saw it in [this github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/issues/929).

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set a the environment variables:

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY.json`

and

`PROJECT_ID=YOUR_GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID`